# not able to connect EC2 instance from local Linux machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to connect EC2 machine from my Linux machine.
But getting a generic issue :

cmd:  `aws ec2 describe-instances --region Ohio`

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL:
>   "https://ec2.Ohio.amazonaws.com/"

Followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

cmd:  `aws ec2 describe-instances --region Ohio`

It should have connected to my EC2 machine.

Comment: First, `Ohio` is not a valid region ID for the AWS SDK. What you are looking for is `us-east-2`. However what are you trying to do? This will simply describe the properties of the EC2 instance. This doesn't *"connect"* to the instance itself in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `us-east-2` instead of `Ohio`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-2
```